# db4o Client See Changes from Another Client

Tags: db4o

I'm running a db4o server with multiple clients accessing it. I just ran into the issue of one client not seeing the changes from another client. From my research on the web, it looks like there are basically two ways to solve it.

1: Call Refresh() on the object (from http://www.gamlor.info/wordpress/2009/11/db4o-client-server-and-concurrency/):

const int activationDeph = 4;

client2.Ext().Refresh(objFromClient2, activationDeph);

2: Instead of caching the IObjectContainer, open a new IObjectContainer for every DB request.

Is that right?

Yes, #1 is more efficient, but is that really realistic to specify which objects to refresh? I mean, when a DB is involved, every time a client accesses it, it should get the latest information. That's why I'm leaning towards #2. Plus, I don't have major efficiency concerns.

So, am I right that those are the two approaches? Or is there another?

And, wait a sec... what happens when your object goes out of scope? On a timer, I call a method that gets an object from the DB server. That method instantiates the object. Since the object went out of scope, it's not there to refresh. And when I call the DB, I don't see the changes from the client. In this case, it seems like the only option is to open a new IObjectContainer. No?

** Edit **

I thought I'd post some code using the solution I finally decided to use. Since there were some serious complexities with using a new IObjectContainer for every call, I'm simply going to do a Refresh() in every method that accesses the DB (see Refresh() line below). Since I've encapsulated my DB access into logic classes, I can make sure to do the Refresh() there, every time. I just tested this and it seems to be working.

Note: The Database variable below is the the db4o IObjectContainer.

```
public static ApplicationServer GetByName(string serverName)
{
    ApplicationServer appServer = (from ApplicationServer server in Database
                                   where server.Name.ToUpperInvariant() == serverName.ToUpperInvariant()
                                   select server).FirstOrDefault();

    Database.Ext().Refresh(appServer, 10);

    return appServer;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) As you said, the major problem with this that you usually really don't know what objects to refresh. 
You can use the c[ommitted event](http://community.versant.com/documentation/reference/db4o-8.0/java/reference/Content/advanced_topics/callbacks/possible_usecases/committed_event_example.htm) to refresh objects as soon as any client has committed. db4o will distribute that event. Note that this also consumes some network traffic & time to send the events. And there will be a time frame where your objects have a stale state.

2) It actually the cleanest method, but not for every db request. Use a object container for every logical unit of work. Any operation which is one 'atomic' unit of work in your business-operations.

Anyway in general. db4o was never build with the client server scenario as first priority, and it shows in the concurrent scenarios. You cannot avoid working with stale (and even inconsistent) object state and there is no concurrency control options (except the low level semaphores).

My recommendation: Use a client container per unit of work. Be aware that even then you might get stale data, which then might lead to a inconsistent view & update. When there are rarely any contentions & races in your application scenario and you can tolerate a mistake once in a while, then this is fine. However if you really need to ensure correctness, then I recommend to use a database which has a better concurrency store =(

Comment: Thanks, Gamlor. This is tough to accept after investing so much time in db4o: "...you can tolerate a mistake once in a while..." How can a DB even be considered for use if there will be mistakes? I've already created a db4o server, and two different apps that use it. Not sure what to do now. RavenDB? Something else?

Comment: Do you really need 100% absolute correctness? Most application do not need that (well financial application need it). So then then the options above are probably 'good enough'. But as said, it really depends on the application. 
Of course you could work around these issues with db4o, but it gets quite fast ridiculous hard. 
To RavenDB: RavenDB is certainly a damn good document database. Be aware that RavenDB per default also allows to return state results. But it's easier to control the staleness and it has optimistic locking support.

Comment: I would say that not having 100% correctness could be catastrophic. I'm creating an automated deployment app. If a user changes a connection string that app servers are supposed to use, and that change isn't seen by the app servers when they update themselves, that's not good.

Comment: There is some complexity with option 2. If we use one IObjectContainer to retrieve an object, then use a different IObjectContainer to save it, that doesn't work. The new IObjectContainer will add a new object to the DB, not save the existing one. Time to try and think of an elegant solution...

Comment: @Update scenario: I would argue that a typical scenario where you can accept some temporary inconsistency. Of course it should happen very rarely and be able to recover from a temporary inconsistency. But you certainly need some refresh-stategy, like the call-back mechanism showed above.